# How to increment visible rows of p:datatable with p:outputLink

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want increment visible rows of p:dataTable when click on p:outputLink. Here is picture:[image]

and my code is:

```
 <p:dataTable   value="#{tasks}" styleClass="dashTable"
  var="tasklar"   rows="5"   lazy="true"   
  selection="#{flowScope.selectedTask}" selectionMode="single" >
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  />

   <p:column headerText="#{messages.label_task_temasy}">
   <h:outputText value="#{tasklar.taskTemasy}"/> </p:column>

  </p:dataTable>
```

Thank`s for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem. Here is code:

```
<h:form id="dataForm">

 <p:dataTable   value="#{tasks}" styleClass="dashTable"
 var="tasklar"   rows="#{taskCriteria.pageSize}"   lazy="true"   
 selection="#{flowScope.selectedTask}" selectionMode="single" >
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect"  />

 <p:column headerText="#{messages.label_task_temasy}">
 <h:outputText value="#{tasklar.taskTemasy}"/> </p:column>

 </p:dataTable>

<p:commandLink style="float:left" update=":dataForm" 
action="#{taskCriteria.setPageSize(taskCriteria.pageSize+5)}">
<h:outputText  value="Show more..." />
</p:commandLink>

</h:form>
```